# How can I turn this Chain of operators in to a reusable operator?

Tags: swift, combine

I created a playground in Swift that prints a number of items from an Array, one at a time with a delay between each as follows:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Combine
import Foundation

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

["a", "b", "c"].enumerated()
    .publisher
    .flatMap { Just($0.element).delay(for: .seconds($0.offset), scheduler: RunLoop.main) }
    .sink { complete in
        print("Complete: \(complete) at \(Date())")
        PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
    } receiveValue: { value in
        print("Value: \(value) at \(Date())")
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

I'd like encapsulate the operators (possibly just the flatMap?) into one that I can use elsewhere. I'd like it to be able to accept any type of element in the array. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You can write your own custom operators. But honestly, don't try to over-engineer it – IMHO, keep it as it is, it's fine.

Comment: How to create the custom operator what I'm asking for as I don't think I'm going to every be able to remember that flatMap line and I'd like to use it in a number of different situations.

Comment: Writing an operator is *hard*. But composing existing operators is not. https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorscomposed.html

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution does not require to write a full blown custom publisher.

A simple "helper" – an extension function for Publisher – may suffice:

```
import Combine

extension Publisher {
    
    func delay<S: Scheduler>(
        interval: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride,
        scheduler: S
    ) -> AnyPublisher<Self.Output, Self.Failure> {
        self.flatMap { value in
            Just(value)
                .delay(for: interval, scheduler: scheduler)
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

}
```

Disclaimer:

Due to the simplicity of the task, I would not vote for writing an extension. Instead, keep things simple and *explicit*, just use the existing operators.

If you want to go for a custom publisher I would recommend to read some useful articles and tutorials. Actually, there are different approaches with varying complexity.

Comment: I like this solution but the code delays all values for the duration of the interval, not each value subsequently. Is there a way I can enumerate the values and multiply the offset but the interval, or is there a better solution? I'm wondering if recursion would be helpful here.

Comment: I provided a very generic approach in order to demo the concept. Frankly, I would rather suggest, you try to understand what `flatMap` means: its body returns a publisher. Whenever this flatMap receives input, it creates a publisher, that will be "invoked" within the flatMap, concurrently to others already "running" in them. When a publisher within this flatMap will eventually complete, it gets removed. So, `flatMap` is some sort of "container" creating and running publishers.

Answer (score 1):

In your case a simple extension would do the job :

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Combine
import Foundation

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

extension Publishers.Sequence<EnumeratedSequence<Array<Any>>, Never> {
    func sequencialPrint()-> AnyCancellable {
        return self.flatMap { Just($0.element).delay(for: .seconds($0.offset), scheduler: RunLoop.main) }
        .sink { complete in
            print("Complete: \(complete) at \(Date())")
            PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
        } receiveValue: { value in
            Swift.print("Value: \(value) at \(Date())")
        }
    }
}


["a", "b", "c"].enumerated()
    .publisher
    .sequencialPrint()
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Note on this exemple, you are bound to be in the playground since you use `PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()`.

if your problem is on the flatmap closure i would just create a utility func for it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

```
extension Publishers {
    static func progressiveDelay<Output, S>(array: [Output], multiplier: Double = 1.0, scheduler: S) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Never>
    where S: Scheduler {
        array
            .enumerated()
            .publisher
            .flatMap { Just($0.element).delay(for: .seconds(Double($0.offset) * multiplier), scheduler: scheduler) }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Which could be used like this:

```
Publishers.progressiveDelay(array: ["a", "b", "c"], scheduler: RunLoop.main)
    .sink { complete in
        print("Complete: \(complete) at \(Date())")
        PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
    } receiveValue: { value in
        print("Value: \(value) at \(Date())")
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```